# Hour, day, week and month subtotals with Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been thinking about how I can store counts of big nodes in my database and be able to compare those counts;

**for example:**

- today vs the same day of past week
- This month vs last month
- This hour vs this hour yesterday
- This hour vs this hour last week on the same day

So I came up with this:

[image]

**The problem is:** nested nested nested.

I do not want to get the whole data if I need only the year data.

**My question: What would be the right structure for my use case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep YYYY, YYYY_MM, YYYY_MM_DD and YYYY_MM_DD_HH formatted nodes. That would be less expensive to retrieve data.

[image]

Comment: Nice one. It's a great solution. Although it might be the only one, I would love to see more suggestions from users (if there are).  Seem like I will be forced to have 720 nodes/month, 8640 nodes / year.